# C++ 11 template sub type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

*With more detail added*

I'm looking to inject in a type and use this as the template type, in addition to this I would like to implicitly pass in a subtype to be used.

Implementation:

```
MyClass<MyTestClass> myClass;

const auto& testDataReturn = myClass.m_typeObject.m_field1;

// looking to be able to call myClass.m_subTypeObject here which is implicitly typed from the parent type (see template def below)
```

Template:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:

    T m_typeObject;
    typename T::SubType m_subTypeObject; // **does not like this**
};

typedef MyType SubType;
```

Class definitions:

```
class SubTypeImpl
{
public:
    std::string m_field1 = "test1Sub";
    std::string m_field2 = "test2Sub";
};

class MyTestClass
{

public:
    std::string m_field1 = "test1";
    SubTypeImpl SubType;
};
```

Comment: Please provide more context, something like a [mcve]. I think I have seen and done things like what I understand you are asking about, but I am not sure. You can get the mcve compileable by deactivating (using comment syntax) the lines which cause errors. it is then easy for others to play with the compileable and non-compileable version. Comments with prose or comments with pseudo code could be helpful, too.

Comment: Your definition of MyClass at least compiles and looks reasonable. But I don't know what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not fully understand the question, but it seems if you change

```
SubTypeImpl SubType;
```

to

```
typedef SubTypeImpl SubType;
```

you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`T::SubType` is not a type, it is a member field.

```
template<class T>
using SubType = decltype(std::declval<T&>().SubType);
```

that gets the type of the `SubType` member of `T`, assuming it is public.

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:

  T m_typeObject;
  SubType<T> m_subTypeObject;
};
```

you could do the `decltype` inline in the `MyClass` definition, but that is messy.